# SVN: Add File Metadata

Tags: svn, version-control

For a project in SVN, it is required that we add some metadata to file versions like *buggy status*, *review status* etc.

I don't think I can use custom properties as it is at the element level and not on the versions.

I thought of adding the metadata in the comment of the commit, but the comment is shared by all file versions of that change set, hence cannot be used.

Is there any SVN feature which can be used for this?

Comment: As far as properties are concerned you can either have regular properties per element (that are versioned), or unversioned revision properties per revision (set with `svn propset --revprop`). Also, I'm not sure what you mean by 'comment shared by all file versions of that change set' - the comment applies to the whole revision that is created by your commit.

Comment: how do i set unversioned properties from Tortoise SVN?

Comment: @maxmelbin, any update on this question? How did you solve your problem? I have a very similar problem to solve.

Answer (score 2):

To set/edit revision properties in TortoiseSVN: right-click on a top-level item in your working copy ->  Show log -> right-lick on revision for which you want to set the properties -> Show revision properties -> push New -> Advanced -> etc.

You do not have to click on the top-level item per se, but you need an item whose log will show the revision you want to set the property for.

Comment: this still applies the property to the entire changeset that is part of that commit. The use-case is that i want to attach a property "buggy=#1234" on a defective version of a file. In this case it will attach this property to all the file versions in the change set that introduced this bug. If i fix it and create a new commit, all the other files that were part of that changeset still shows the property as buggy.

Comment: Well, I think your only other option is to use regular (versioned) properties and change them whenever the status changes. Think of properties as something that is attached to an element that SVN can read. As long as you do not change it - it stays the same version after version. When you do change it - it works like regular changes in your files - if you get an older revision you'll get the older property.